# Anyone know how to turn off "new unread mail" number in Apple Mail?

Tags: mail.app, email

See image below. I want to turn off the little number that shows how many new unread e-mails you've received, so that's not distracting me while I'm working in Apple Mail...any quick fixes?[image]

Comment: The answer to your question: Not really. I guess if it were so, someone would have answered already. One quick idea: have an Applescript mark any incoming email as read, and then apply a flag to it, so you can tell new from already-read mail. I am sure a similar script exists somewhere or could be made quite fast.